# porting MSVS proj files to makefiles?

Tags: visual-c++

Does anyone know if/how to automatically generate makefiles from a .sln/.vcproj files of a C++ application in MSVS to be used to compile and build this application on Linux ?

Thanks, --Yariv

Answer (score 0):

You can create a makefile from within Visual Studio. It's not exactly the same thing as in Linux, but the numner of required modifications is not too big.

[MSDN: Creating a Makefile Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx%28VS.80%29.aspx)